# Window manager with cropping, pinning and popup?

Tags: window-manager, windows-10

[OnTopReplica](https://ontopreplica.codeplex.com/) let's me's mirror a segment of a window on top of whatever else i'm doing. It doesn't manipulate the window itself though. Many alternatives pin windows on top, but i desire one that also selectively crops the window as OnTopReplica does. Fuctionality to detect activity within a windows (such as new messages) and respond by popping it up would be a nice bonus.

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: On the front page of OnTopReplica it says: "Completely written in C# for .NET 4.0/4.5, makes use of the Windows Forms Aero library.". What are you asking for?  Do you want us to traverse the source code for you? Do you want us to make a new program? Are you looking for guidance in how to use OnTopReplica?  Please clarify your question, and details as to what you are really looking for.

Comment: That the trick?